# Question incorrectly migrated to site where it's off-topic

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

I recently posted a [question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/84769/did-hermann-gunkel-believe-that-cultic-poetry-and-psalms-were-the-same-genre) about a specific theologian's views. However, it was migrated to Biblical Hermeneutics, where it's off-topic for not being about a specific text. (I deliberately posted the question on this site for that exact reason). Is there some way to reverse the migration?

Comment: It's not off topic on BH.SE. Is Gunkel really a theologian? He looks more like a Biblical scholar, again fitting BH.SE more.

Comment: However note that if it is closed on BH.SE (even though I don't think it should be), it would then be a "rejected migration" and would be returned to this site. It would then have to be reopened here, though I'm not sure it would be as I'm not sure many would consider it on-topic here.